# Spacemacs setup on mac

Tags: spacemacs, osx

Long time vim user, finally decided to try emacs for orgmode. As usual, lost in configuration and found out about spacemacs.

Excited to try, unfortunately after all the attempts I still can't get couple of things.

- The UI doesn't look correct (as per their home page). I am not sure what is gone wrong. (I have tried in terminal as well as iterm2)
- Inline image preview (C-x C-c C-v) is not working in orgmode/emacs. The same issue with vanila homebrew emacs as well.

[image: Spacemacs ui]
[image: inline images]

I have followed the steps: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#macos

Answer (score 3):

Stupid me, it is working as expected. Spacemacs looks like the screenshot from their site and images in my org files show up inline :-)

You are expected to open the application in GUI mode (from /Application like any other app) and I was trying to do in a terminal.

[image: Happy Spacemacs]